# Browser cache issues

Tags: vue.js, browser-cache, vue-cli

I'm working on an online platform built on Vue CLI and i am experiencing problems with browser cache :

**This is my scenario:**

For each modification I make to the platform I need to build my application again (npm run build) . After that I push to a testing branch and do some other operations before going to production. At the end of the process, the old files are replaced by the new ones generated in the bundle.

> And here comes my problem: when my customers go to access the platform after an update it
> often doesn't load because they still have the old files in their browser's cache. Whenever
> this happens, I advise them to clear their browser's cache and everything goes back to
> normal, but this is quite inconvenient.
> could someone give me any suggestion of what i could do to prevent this from happening
> whenever i modify my platform files?

Comment: Where do you host your site?

Comment: My application is hosted on AWS.

Comment: static or ssr and do you use a service worker?

Comment: Well these are two concepts that I don't know very well (ssr and service worker) I didn't implement either. What I did was basically hire a machine on EC2 to host the application and use the RDS for the database. I just copied the files generated in the bundle to the apache  directory (/ var / www / html / myapplication).  https://soniaserranoexpert.sabiorealm.com/ this was exactly my client who had problems.

Comment: Every customer has his own subdomain and his own directory in Apache. So when I updated your platform I took all the new files generated in the bundle and replaced it in your directory, which in this case was / var / www / html / soniaserranoexpert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is the default configuration of the project generated by vue-cli

webpack.prod.conf.js:

```js
output: {
  path: config.build.assetsRoot,
  filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
  chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
},
```

You can see that the file name after `npm run build` has a hash value added like `js/vendor.658937d99bd7b1009d76.js`, so there should be no cache problem.

Then it may be that the compiled `index.html` file is cached on the server side, which requires modifying the server configuration to not cache the `index.html` file.

For example, nginx configuration:

```
location / {
   root  html;
   add_header  Cache-Control no-store;
   index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

This way the browser will not cache the `index.html` file when loading.

Comment: Ah understood!! I was really thinking about it even if the problem was clientside or serveride caching. It makes a lot of sense! I will try to perform this same configuration for apache :) thanks!

Comment: nginx configuration: location '/' will match all requests , including 'js, css' files referenced in the index.html

Answer (score 2):

Although this question has already has an accepted answer, i still want to add an another answer:

Regarding resources referenced by index.html, e.g. (*.js, *.css)
Agree with the accepted answer, we just need to add hash value to those files.

Regarding index.html itself, i think we should update nginx configuration like below:

```
location /index.html {
   root  html;
   add_header  Cache-Control no-store;
   index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

we only add no cache header for index.html, rather than to all of the requests